# How can I change the date format in Firefox without changing the language in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, date

I want to display dates in Firefox as `DD.MM.YYYY`, despite the fact that I'm using the en-us version of Firefox, which causes the date to be in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

I would like to continue using the `en-us` version of Firefox. Also Windows is set to `DD.MM.YYYY` format. How can I change the date format in Firefox without changing the language in Firefox?

Comment: It's probably just easiest to switch to UK English. It will flip the dates & about the only other difference will be where $ and € move to.

Comment: The two dates in your post are identical... What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @harrymc "en-us version" will default to MM.DD.YYYY

Comment: @Tetsujin: I would like the poster to explain things better.

Comment: I have edited the post. @Tetsujin did explain it properly. The question is exactly how to avoid changing to the UK version and still make the change.

Answer (score 12):

To decouple Firefox display language from the regional format used for dates, time, etc., just set the flag `intl.regional_prefs.use_os_locales` to `true`.

To do this, open a new tab in Firefox, type `about:config` in the address bar and hit enter, proceed to agree to the warning message and use the search bar to find `intl.regional_prefs.use_os_locales`. Toggle the flag value to `true` and restart the browser.

It should look like this:
[image: Should look like this]

This will enable a new option in Firefox language settings like so:

[image: Firefox Settings]

It's now possible to switch between Firefox language defined formats and your operating system preferred formats.

In Windows you can personalize your regional format settings using the good ol' Control Panel:

[image: Region settings]

Using the additional settings:

[image: Additional settings]

You could customize the date format to your needs. Keep in mind that these are system wide settings and will apply to others apps besides Firefox.

To know more about how these things work under the hood refer to [Local management documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/intl/locale.html#regional-preferences). This [Mozilla Support question](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1215016) might be useful too.

##### This was tested on Windows 11 22H2 and Firefox 116.